# How to track referral install from Android Market?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have this in my manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but I don't see the install data in my GA. I am wondering if I missed out something.

Answer (score 3):

This is code snippet correct. But it need for track information about installations by using referral link. You can generate this link [here](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#android-market-tracking). So if user found your application by this link and then he installed your application, in this case will be recorded referral parameters. (Please see more about referral parameters by link above).

If you want simply track installations of your application, you will can track some pageview (e.g /app/install) only once, at first run of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have **another BroadcastReceiver** in your manifest?

The [docs](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#referrals) say:

> Note: Only one BroadcastReceiver class can be specified per application. Should you need to incorporate two or more BroadcastReceivers from different SDKs, you will need to create your own BroadcastReceiver class that will receive all broadcasts and call the appropriate BroadcastReceivers for each type of Broadcast.